# I am running a Gatsby Graphql queries successfully with GraphiQL, but on NextJS (GraphQL queries configured with Apollo) the same queries don't work?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, graphiql

- Just to confirm, both the NextJS and Gatsby are connected to a Strapi api which ARE GraphQL compatible and I have the server running on http://localhost:1337
- ALSO, I can access the GraphQL playground through http://localhost:1337/graphql

HOWEVER, Gatsby gives me the ability to run GraphQL also through GraphiQL on http://localhost:8000/___graphiql and this is where my discrepancies begin...

- The GraphiQL on http://localhost:8000/ that Gatsby provides is absolutely awesome.
  I prefer it to the GraphQL playground which you will see down in the bottom screenshot in dark mode on http://localhost:1337/graphql

Here is the successful GraphQL query on Gatsby which I run through GraphiQL:
[image]

- I want the same query within GraphiQL to work within the Strapi backend server on http://localhost:1337/graphql
- Just to be exact, here is the GraphQL query that ran successfully on GraphiQL:

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiProduct(filter: {featured: {eq: true}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        strapiId
        variants {
          price
          qty
          product
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here I am trying to run the GraphQL query through my Strapi backend server via the standard GraphQL playground on http://localhost:1337/graphql so that I can include it within my NextJS project:
[image]

Please help get this GraphiQL query and all the other GraphiQL queries I ran through Gatsby to work via NextJS!

Comment: have you downloaded the schema?  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/downloading-schema/ can you share the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your two GraphQL servers are serving different schemas.  That is, while `allStrapiProduct` works in GraphiQL, you need to use `product` in strapi.  Likewise, `filter` in GraphiQL but `where` in strapi.

[image: different schemas]